# Custom Django template tag is not accessible at all pages

Tags: django, jinja2

I am creating an app where there is no **database** because I am working with `rest API`, so the thing I want to show user phone number on the top of navbar at every page, I created a custom **template** tag and I am calling `get_user_phone(user_phone)` whenever someone logs in and pass that logged in user to this method  and after loading the tag in the base template I am seeing the phone number but the issue is all other other pages which are extended  by that base page is not showing this phone number

```
@register.simple_tag()
def get_user_phone(user_phone):
    return user_phone
```

I am accesssing the user phone like this after loading the template

```
{% get_user_phone user_phone %}
```

below is my base views file

```
    {% load post_tags %}
    {% load static %}
    <a>{% get_user_phone user_phone %} </a>
 {% block  content %}
 {% endblock  content %}
```

below is my dashbaord.html file where I can see the phone number

```
{% extends "app/committee/com-base.html" %}


{% block  content %}
{% endblock  content %}
```

below is my edit profile.html file I can't see the phone number here

```
{% extends "app/committee/com-base.html" %}


{% block  content %}
{% endblock  content %}
```

Comment: If you just want to display user's phone number you can display dirctly you don't have to create template tag for it

Comment: It is worth checking if you are passing the correct context to the views/templates in order to render template tag on other pages. Related blocks might be also overwritten on those pages and that could explain why you don't see the content.

Comment: All other changes in base file at that html is being shown at other pages, but phone number just gets hidden at other pages

Comment: Can you show your `views`, please?

Comment: @NixonSparrow I have edit the questions and added the structure

Comment: `views.py`, not templates.